# Stan dimensions mismatch

Tags: python, stan, pystan

PyStan (imported as Stan) is giving me an unexpected error

```
import stan

# Load data (replace X and y with your actual data)
X = np.linspace(1,100,100).reshape([100,1])
y = np.random.randint(0,2,100).reshape([100,1])

N = y.shape[0]
K = X.shape[1]
data = {'N': N, 'K': K, 'X': X, 'y': y}

# Compile Stan model
posterior = stan.build(lr_model, data=data, random_seed=1)

# Fit the model
samples = posterior.sample(data=data, iter=1000, chains=4)
```

**Error**:

```
Exception: mismatch in number dimensions declared and found in context; processing stage=data initialization; variable name=y; dims declared=(100); dims found=(100,1) (in '/tmp/httpstan_ii3yhtja/model_776ng6bg.stan', line 7, column 2 to column 35)
```

I don't understand why Stan is expecting 100 not (100,1) and how to fix. I've tried using lists instead of arrays but the same error was returned.

Here's the script

```
lr_model = """
data {
  int<lower=0> N;          // number of observations
  int<lower=0> K;          // number of predictors
  matrix[N, K] X;          // predictor matrix
  array[N] int<lower=0, upper=1> y; // binary response
}

parameters {
  vector[K] beta;          // regression coefficients
}

model {
  beta ~ normal(0, 1);
  y ~ bernoulli_logit(X * beta);
}
"""
```